# Unity Can not Build because of IL2CPP Problem Unity 2019.2.17f1

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk, armv7

I can't build my unity project.

Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.17f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe', CommandLine='--convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="Android" --architecture="ARMv7" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="D:\unity\BubbleBee\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a\libil2cpp.so" --cachedirectory="D:\unity\BubbleBee\Assets..\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache" --additional-include-directories="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.17f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\bdwgc/include" --additional-include-directories="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.17f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\libil2cpp/include" --tool-chain-path="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.17f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/android-ndk-r16b" --profiler-report --map-file-parser="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.17f1/Editor/Data/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser.exe" --directory=D:/unity/BubbleBee/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed --generatedcppdir=D:/unity/BubbleBee/Temp/StagingArea/Il2Cpp/il2cppOutput ', CurrentDirectory='D:\unity\BubbleBee\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed', Native error= İstenen işlem için yükseltme gerekiyor.

System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) (at :0)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () (at :0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start (System.EventHandler exitCallback) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/Program.cs:44)
UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/Program.cs:28)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:104)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:71)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:503)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (System.String inputDirectory, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory, System.Boolean platformSupportsManagedDebugging) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:484)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:334)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:63)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <502f1b7df2d7430696af84c6f02852ed>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:281)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)

Comment: I don't think most (or maybe even any?) of the System.Diagnostics namespace is supported by IL2CPP.

Answer (score 2):

In `PlayerSetting -> Configurations` change `Target Architecture` to `ARM64`.

Answer (score 0):

Install this ("NDP471-DevPack-ENU") software or

Comment: Install this software or...?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinstall Unity by its installer then select "Windows Build" during the install

Answer (score -1):

C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe path right click on il2cpp.exe -> properties -> compatiblity -> select run this program as an administrator and change this setting to all user -> apply -> ok